# IProgress<T> does not fire events in current context

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I've managed to implement a `Task` in my class **UpdateManager** that downloads a file from my webspace.

```
public async Task DownloadPackageTask(IProgress<int> progress) 
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.mywebspace.de/archive.zip"));
        using (var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            FileStream fileStream = File.Create("Path"));
            using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                int received = 0;
                double total = 0d;
                var size = GetFileSize(new Uri("...")); // Gets the content length with a request as the Stream.Length-property throws an NotSupportedException
                if (size != null) 
                    total = (long) size.Value;

                int size = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (size > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    received += size;
                    progress.Report((received/total)*100));
                    size = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works well, the file is being downloaded and also if I add `Debug.Print((received/total)*100)` it outputs the correct percentage, everything is alright. The method is marked as async so that it can be awaited/wrapped asynchronously in a task.
The problem occurs in another class **UpdaterUi** that is basically the interface between the manager and the user interface and calls the method like that:

```
            public void ShowUserInterface()
            {
                TaskEx.Run(async delegate
                {           
                    var downloadDialog = new UpdateDownloadDialog
                    {
                        LanguageName = _updateManager.LanguageCulture.Name,
                        PackagesCount = _updateManager.PackageConfigurations.Count()
                    };

                    _context.Post(downloadDialog.ShowModalDialog, null); // Do this with a SynchronizationContext as we are not on the UI thread.

                    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>();
                    progressIndicator.ProgressChanged += (sender, value) =>
                    downloadDialog.Progress = value;


                   await TaskEx.Run(() => _updateManager.DownloadPackageTask(progressIndicator));
                });
            }
```

It never calls the anonymous method there that should be invoked as soon as the progress changes, but nothing happens, I debugged it with breakpoints.

The problem is maybe that the `progressIndicator` is not created on the UI-thread, but on the new thread created by `TaskEx.Run`. It doesn't fire the event and consecutively the UI does not update the progressbar it contains (which it does in the setter of the `Progress`-property that is initialized above).

The problem is that I don't know what to do in order to make it working, how am I supposed to change the implementation in my project to get it working, is my thought of that threading problem correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must both **create** and **update** UI elements on the UI thread. You only appear to be trying to **show** it on the UI thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity If I understand you correctly, that is why I use a `SynchronizationContext` there to basically create the UI stuff. This context is provided in the `UpdaterUi` when instantiating it and represents `SynchronizationContext.Current` which is handled over. The class is instantiated and the method is being called in the handler of a button's click event and should then provide the correct context.

Comment: The creation of `UpdateDownloadDialog` is done inside the task - it should be on the UI thread. The `progressIndicator.ProgressChanged` is trying to update the UI on the task thread. Both of those are not using the sync context.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, I changed that as also Sriram provided me with that tip in the answer below, thanks. :)
Only one thing that is kind of a problem is that it does not execute after the call of `await _updateManager.DownloadPackageTask(progressReporter);`. Do you know why? Basically I wanted to create a new question for that, but as it is relating to the context maybe I can ask here, too.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ah, now it works, forgot the `UpdateDownloadDialog` when moving the dialogs out. ^^ Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your speculation about the problem is right. `Progress<T>` should be created in UI thread in order to be notified in UI thread.

It works by capturing the `SynchronizationContext` and posting the delegate for execution in the captured context. Since it is created in non UI context(default context or threadpool context), it will raise `ProgressChanged` in threadpool thread.

If you move this line `var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>();` out of the `TaskEx.Run`, it should work (if `ShowUserInterface` is called from UI thread).

I see you're creating `UpdateDownloadDialog` in a worker thread. You shouldn't do that. Move that also to UI thread.

Comment: Yep, that method is called in the UI-thread of a Windows Form. The point with moving it out of the created thread by `TaskEx.Run` made it working. I will move the instantiated forms etc. out of that task's inner scope, too, thanks for the tip!

I were not sure if that would solve the problem correctly but that seems to do it for me, thanks so much!